# Can Jaxb use one ValueObject to map different xml in Unmarshalling By XmlAdapter

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

I have two Xml files
one is

```
<A>
    <B>xxx</B>
</A>
```

the other is

```
<A>
<B>
<C>xxx</C>
</B>
</A>
```

for `B` element, I made a `ValueObject` with a `String` field.
also, I made a `XmlAdapter<Object, ValueObject>` with a `boolean` property for `B` element,
and I can `setAdapter(BXmlAdapter.class, new BxmlAdaper(boolean))` when unmarshalling,
so I can tell `BxmlAdaper` when try to convert from a `String`, when try to convert from a `ValueObject`.

if the element `B` has a attribute `xsi:type="prefix:ValueObject"` for the first xml
and `xsi:type="xs:string"` for the second `xml`. it works well. I can unmarshall all of them with one
`ValueObject`. 
but without `xsi:type`, I got a instance of `org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl` in `XmlAdapter` unmarshall method.
how can I resolve this case.

I also have two schema files for these two `xml` files, So I have thought maybe I can use `schema` file
to tell JAXB What the type of `B` element is. but it seems that JAXB Just uses schema file to check.
do I miss something?

Here is the samle code
Class A

```
package example.dto;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import example.adapter.BXmlAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BXmlAdapter.class)
    private B b;

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Class B

```
    package example.dto;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="B")
public class B {

    private String test;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

}
```

package-info

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, namespace = "http://test/test", xmlns = @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "test", namespaceURI = "http://test/test"))
package example.dto;
```

jaxb.index

```
A
B
```

BXmlAdapter.java

```
    package example.adapter;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

import example.dto.B;

public class BXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, B> {

    private final boolean flg;

    public BXmlAdapter() {
        this.flg = false;
    }

    public BXmlAdapter(boolean flg) {
        this.flg = flg;
    }

    @Override
    public Object marshal(B v) throws Exception {
        if (flg) {
            return v.getTest();
        } else {
            return v;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public B unmarshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        if (flg) {
            B b = new B();
            b.setTest((String) v);
            return b;
        } else {
            return (B) v;
        }
    }
}
```

A1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test:a xmlns:test="http://test/test">
    <test:b xsi:type="test:B" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <test:test>xxxx</test:test>
    </test:b>
</test:a>
```

A2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test:a xmlns:test="http://test/test">
    <test:b xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">xxxx2</test:b>
</test:a>
```

Xml2JavaObject.java

```
   import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import example.adapter.BXmlAdapter;
import example.dto.A;

public class Xml2JavaObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            SAXException {
        try {
            File file = new File("D:\\jaxb\\A1.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("example.dto");
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            jaxbUnmarshaller.setAdapter(BXmlAdapter.class,
                    new BXmlAdapter(false));
            A a = (A) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(a.getB().getTest());
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            File file = new File("D:\\jaxb\\A2.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("example.dto");
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            jaxbUnmarshaller.setAdapter(BXmlAdapter.class,
                    new BXmlAdapter(true));
            A a = (A) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(a.getB().getTest());
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The code above works fine,
but if there are no xsi:type in xml files.
it does not work.
the parameter of unmarshal method in BXmlAdapter is a instance of 
ElementNSImpl....

And My question is

1. How to handle the ElementNSImpl instance
2. If there is no xsi:type in xml file, Can JAXB handle different xml file by using one ValueObject
3. the xsi:type is also in schema file. Can JAXB use schema file to decide the type? it seems JAXB
   just uses schema file in validation.

Thanks

Comment: Please, post your code

Comment: Do you want the contents of the `B` and `C` elements to map to a `String` property on the class corresponding to the `A` element?  Or in the second XML example will `A` hold an instance of `B`?

Comment: I have post my sample code. hope they can make the question clearly.thanks

Comment: HI, Blaise Doughan, I want to use an A class to marshall & unmarshall with two or more particular xmls that have a little difference.

Answer (score 0):

I find a little ugly way to resolve this by using @XmlMixed And XmlAdapter.
Here is the code
class A

```
package example.dto;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import example.adapter.BXmlAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=BXmlAdapter.class)
    private B b;

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

}
```

class B

```
package example.dto;

public class B {

    private String test;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

}
```

class XmlB

```
package example.dto;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlMixed;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "B")
public class XmlB {

    @XmlMixed
    private List<Object> tempElement;

    private String test;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public List<Object> getTempElement() {
        return tempElement;
    }

    public void setTempElement(List<Object> tempElement) {
        this.tempElement = tempElement;
    }

}
```

package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, namespace = "http://test/test", xmlns = @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "test", namespaceURI = "http://test/test"))
package example.dto;
```

jaxb.index

```
A
XmlB
```

A1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test:a xmlns:test="http://test/test">
    <test:b>
        <test:test>xxxx</test:test>
    </test:b>
</test:a>
```

A2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test:a xmlns:test="http://test/test">
    <test:b>xxxx2</test:b>
</test:a>
```

BXmlAdapter.java

```
package example.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

import example.dto.B;
import example.dto.XmlB;

public class BXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<XmlB, B> {

    private final boolean flg;

    public BXmlAdapter() {
        this.flg = false;
    }

    public BXmlAdapter(boolean flg) {
        this.flg = flg;
    }

    @Override
    public XmlB marshal(B v) throws Exception {

        XmlB xmlb = new XmlB();

        if (flg) {
            List<Object> tempElement = new ArrayList<>();
            tempElement.add(v.getTest());
            xmlb.setTempElement(tempElement);
        } else {
            xmlb.setTest(v.getTest());
        }

        return xmlb;
    }

    @Override
    public B unmarshal(XmlB v) throws Exception {
        B b = new B();
        if (flg) {
            if (v.getTempElement() != null && v.getTempElement().size() == 1) {
                b.setTest((String) v.getTempElement().get(0));
            }
        } else {
            b.setTest(v.getTest());
        }

        return b;
    }

}
```

JavaObject2Xml.java

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import example.adapter.BXmlAdapter;
import example.dto.A;
import example.dto.B;

public class JavaObject2Xml {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        A a1 = new A();
        A a2 = new A();
        B b1 = new B();
        B b2 = new B();
        b1.setTest("xxxx");
        b2.setTest("xxxx2");

        a1.setB(b1);
        a2.setB(b2);

        try {

            File fileA1 = new File("D:\\jaxb\\A1.xml");

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("example.dto");
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.setAdapter(BXmlAdapter.class, new BXmlAdapter(false));
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(a1, fileA1);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            File fileA2 = new File("D:\\jaxb\\A2.xml");

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("example.dto");
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.setAdapter(BXmlAdapter.class, new BXmlAdapter(true));
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(a2, fileA2);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Xml2JavaObject.java

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import example.adapter.BXmlAdapter;
import example.dto.A;

public class Xml2JavaObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            SAXException {
        try {
            File file = new File("D:\\jaxb\\A1.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("example.dto");
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            jaxbUnmarshaller.setAdapter(BXmlAdapter.class, new BXmlAdapter(false));
            A a = (A) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(a.getB().getTest());
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            File file = new File("D:\\jaxb\\A2.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("example.dto");
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            jaxbUnmarshaller.setAdapter(BXmlAdapter.class,new BXmlAdapter(true));
            A a = (A) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(a.getB().getTest());
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The code above can help me to use one group of Classes to handle 2 or more xml file